# Changing the generated name of a foreign key in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

```
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="vehicle_id", referencedColumnName="vehicleId")
public Vehicle getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}
```

My UserDetails class has a one-to-one mapping with the Entitity class Vehicle. `Hibernate` creates the 2 tables and assigns a generic Foreign Key, which maps the vehicle_id column (UserDetails table.) to the primary key vehicleId (Vehicle table).

```
KEY FKB7C889CEAF42C7A1 (vehicle_id),
CONSTRAINT FKB7C889CEAF42C7A1 FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES vehicle (vehicleId)
```

My question is : how do we change this generated foreign key, into something meaningful, like Fk_userdetails_vehicle for example.

Comment: @Ashok_udhay Since errors with regard to foreign keys usually just result in the name of the foreign key being spit out by the database, naming the keys gives you some context of what the key is for without having to track it down first in your db creation scripts.

Comment: Just for the curious (and probably too obvious to state); Hibernate is known to use table and property names to generate its constraint/foreign key names ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766848/how-does-hibernate-generate-foreign-key-constraint-names)); so the seemingly "random" name will actually remain unchanged, unless you actually change your schema. The MD5 step is what renders the final result "not meaningful", or rather "not human-readable".

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since JPA 2.1, you can use the [@javax.persistence.ForeignKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html) annotation:

```
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="vehicle_id", referencedColumnName="vehicleId", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "Fk_userdetails_vehicle"))
public Vehicle getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}
```

Prior to JPA 2.1, you could use Hibernate’s [@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/annotations/ForeignKey.html) annotation, but this is now deprecated:

```
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="vehicle_id", referencedColumnName="vehicleId")
@ForeignKey(name="Fk_userdetails_vehicle")
public Vehicle getVehicle() {
   return vehicle;
}
```

Comment: `The annotation @ForeignKey is disallowed for this location`.

Comment: use the hibernate foreign key annotation, don't use javax.persistence.ForeignKey, then it works

Comment: This answer uses deprecated, Hibernate-specific API instead of the readily available JPA conforming API. It was probably good in 2013, but now it’s not the best answer anymore.

Comment: how to generate this @ForeignKey name from database automatically using JPA project?

Answer (score 28):

Also you can use `@ForeignKey` embedded in  `@JoinColumn` like this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "BAR_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = FK_BAR_OF_FOO))
```

for `@ManyToMany` relations you can use `foreignKey` and `inverseForeignKey` embedded in `@JoinTable` like this:

```
@JoinTable(name = "ARC_EMPLOYEE_OF_BAR"
        , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "BAR_ID")}
        , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")}
        , uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "ARC_UK_EMPLOYEE_OF_BAR", columnNames = {"EMPLOYEE_ID", "BAR_ID"})}
        , foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "ARC_FK_BAR_OF_EMPLOYEE")
        , inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "ARC_FK_EMPLOYEE_OF_BAR"))
```

Comment: Thx. Work with javax.persistence.*

Comment: Doesn't work for me (ManyToMany). Hibernate still tries to create FK constraint with its own name.

Comment: This also works for `@OneToMany` relationships using the intersection table.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it also by implementing `ImplicitNamingStrategy.determineForeignKeyName` and using

```
configuration.setImplicitNamingStrategy(
    new MyImplicitNamingStrategy())
```

which is nice as you don't have to do it manually again and again. However, it may be hard to put the relevant information there. I tried to concat everything I got (using three underscore to separate the parts) and ended up with

```
FK_ACCESS_TEMPLATE____TEMPLATE____TEMPLATE_ID____TEMPLATE_ID__INDEX_B
```

which isn't really better than

```
FKG2JM5OO91HT64EWUACF7TJCFN_INDEX_B
```

I guess, using just the referenced table and column names together with a number for uniqueness would be just fine.

---

Note also that this seems to be legacy Hibernate stuff, unsupported by JPA.

OTOH it works with Hibernate 5.0.1 (just one week old).

Answer (score -2):

May be you should try this, adding `@ForeignKey` annotation :

```
@ManyToOne
@ForeignKey(name="FK_some_model")
@JoinColumn(name="some_model_id")
private SomeModel someModel
```