# how to set ForeignKey name when I have @ManyToMany

Tags: hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, naming

I'm creating databases using JPA classes.

If we have **ManyToOne** relation, we can override  ForeignKey name name like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_COUNTRY"))
private Country country;
```

In DB, we will have such a result:

[image]

Ok, that's nice.  good result!

BUT I will not manage to set my own FK names when I have @ManyToMany.

How can I create this? I try something like this, but it does not works:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "NEW_TABLE",  foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_TEST"))
```

Or something like this:

```
@JoinTable(
        name="NEW_TABLE",
        joinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="ID1", referencedColumnName="ID",  foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_DEV_ID")),
        inverseJoinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="ID2", referencedColumnName="ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_DEV_ZONE"))
    )
```

Or this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name="NEW_TABLE_2",
            joinColumns=
                @JoinColumn(name="ID1", referencedColumnName="ID", 
                            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_1")
                ),
            inverseJoinColumns=
                @JoinColumn(name="ID2", referencedColumnName="ID", 
                            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_2")
                ),
            
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_1"),
            inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_2")
    )  

private List<MyObject> deviceZones;
```

They does not work.

I use this version of jars:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And my java version is 1.8

Comment: have you tried adding the inverseForeignKey attribute too?

Comment: @Giovanni Yes, I have updated my question. I have written this one (if it is true) in my question.

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? I recall seeing some bugs in this area: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8783 for example.

Comment: version is 4.3.6.Final

Comment: I am also having the same issue with 4.3.5.Final.  The bug should be fixed in 5.0 or 6.0?  See: [HHH-8862](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8862)

Comment: I think this is related to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9436

Comment: For me, your third variant worked fine. Hibernate 5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by hibernate bug. I was testing on hibernate 4.3.X.  Solution: Update hibernate version. The problem is fixed in newer versions

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have some jar conflicts there. 
I suggest to do this:

1. remove the following jars: hibernate-commons-annotations and hibernate-entitymanager
2. then look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564789/changing-the-generated-name-of-a-foreign-key-in-hibernate) how you can change
   the name of the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, if you can modify the DB structure is will be easier to generate just one foreign key

```
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="vehicle_id", referencedColumnName="vehicleId")
@ForeignKey(name="Fk_userdetails_vehicle")
public Vehicle getVehicle() {
   return vehicle;
}
```