# How to set the constraint name of a @OneToOne mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@OneToOne
private AnyEntity entity;
```

`hibernate` will create a mapping as follows:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_kcn86scsc0pasdasdngmrqc5i0 FOREIGN KEY (text_id)
 REFERENCES some_table (id) MATCH SIMPLE
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Question: how can I set the constraint **name** explicit from within java?

I cannot introduce a bidirectional mapping, as the `AnyEntity` class will be used in multiple other `@Entity` classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the generated name of a foreign key in Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564789/changing-the-generated-name-of-a-foreign-key-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@ForeignKey` annotation.

```
@ForeignKey(name="constraint_name")
```

Comment: No, this will set the name of `FOREIGN KEY (contraint_name)`, but I want to change the `fk_...` name.

Comment: @membersound Have you tried it? It seems to be the right solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16564911/1225328.

Comment: I found out that `@ForeignKey` annotation is disallowed on fields. But it can be used as follows: `@JoinColumn(name = "BAR_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = FK_BAR_OF_FOO))`, which worked as expected.