# How to specify foreign key with the join column?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

My code is as below. I am using the spring boot with jpa and postgresql database
I need user friendly name as foreign key.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="course_table")
    public class Course extends BaseAuditingEntity {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "course_program_table", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "course_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_program_id")), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "program_id", referencedColumnName = "program_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_course_id")))
    private List programs;
    }
```

I have given the name of foreign key using the @ForeignKey annotation but when I see db it is showing the randomly created foreignkey name.

```
CREATE TABLE course_program_table
(
    course_id integer NOT NULL,
    program_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_28c95hl4nqclyvyxuduei5nbf FOREIGN KEY (program_id)
        REFERENCES public.program_table (program_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_5sainywquv8yyu24pjk3jptn7 FOREIGN KEY (course_id)
        REFERENCES public.course_table (course_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I need foreign key as mentioned in the annotation like fk_program_id and fk_course_id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did hibernate generate that table? You don't even need to specify a FK in your code. It is purely optional

Comment: Yes, Hibernate is generating the table but I want the name of FK is as mentioned in annotation.

Comment: Check this link. Could be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564789/changing-the-generated-name-of-a-foreign-key-in-hibernate

Comment: Have you tried to specify the `@ForeignKey` explicitly instead of have it nested in other annotations?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that solution but it is not working.

Comment: @parthivrshah what is the error when you try to specify the FK explicitly

Comment: It is not giving any error but in the db it creates randomly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "tten_courseservice_course_program_table", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "course_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "program_id", referencedColumnName = "program_id"))
@ForeignKey(name="fk_tten_courseservice_course_table_course_id",inverseName="fk_tten_courseservice_program_table_program_id")
private List<ProgramEntity> programs;``
```

I have tried this and now I am able to generate foreign key name properly.

Hope it will help other.

Answer (score 5):

With a join table this is how you should specify it

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "course_program_table", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", ...)
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_program_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "program_id", ...)
    inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_course_id"))
private List programs;
```

This is how I do it with the JPA provider I use (not Hibernate), and that is why the `@JoinTable` has the "foreignKey"/"inverseForeignKey" attributes (the FKs are on/owned by the join table).

If that doesn't work then you need to be looking at raising a bug on your chosen JPA provider.

Comment: I have tried this ...It is not giving any error but in the database it creates randomly generated foreign key.

Comment: So you need to raise a bug on the jpa provider you are using

Comment: Works correctly with Quarkus Hibernate 1.13.7.
The accepted answer didn't work for me, beacause there is no `inverseName` in `@javax.persistence.ForeignKey`

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers worked for me, but I had to add additional unique contraints, else I could see additional unique keys generated in liquibase changesets.

The following covered all of the keys.

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_COURSE_MAPPING",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="FK__STUDENT_COURSE_MAPPING__STUDENT"),
            inverseForeignKey = @ForeignKey(name="FK__STUDENT_COURSE_MAPPING__COURSE"),
            uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name="UK__STUDENT_COURSE_MAPPING",columnNames = {"STUDENT_ID","COURSE_ID"})
    )
    private Set<Course> courses;
```